# Gradle Build type customization for different Flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I am trying to specify build types for each of my gradle flavors. So the structure would be

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            buildTypes {
                debug {
                    packageNameSuffix ".flavor1"
                    versionNameSuffix "flavor1"
                }
                release {
                    packageNameSuffix ".flavor1"
                    versionNameSuffix "flavor1"
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.foo
                }
            }
        }
        flavor2 {
            buildTypes {
                debug {}
                release {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.bar
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is because I have some functionality which only applies to one flavor, but then I need to be able to specify the package name suffix and signing configs for the different build types under those flavors (And the flavor1-release signing config != flavor2-release signing config.

This isn't working. It appears that all of the options get set no matter which flavor I choose.

I'm unsure how to resolve this. I've tried putting if conditionals to test if the task currently being run is for flavor1 or flavor2 and then setting the build type values, but that didn't work either.

Something tells me I am trying to do something that is unsupported and will need to rethink my build structure. but I thought that maybe someone out there knows for sure. I've looked at the Gradle docs but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.